# How to encode special character like ’ (NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding) in Swift2

Tags: encoding, swift2, ios9, nsurl

As in `Swift2` `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding()` is deprecated instead of `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters()` is used.

But how to encode the especial character like ' % & in `swift2`

For example in `iOS8`(swift1.2) i used following code for encoding

```
NSURL(string: "myurl.php?deviceName=name’phone".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding)!)
```

it work fine i.e. on server it decode correctly.

But in `iOS9`(Swift2.0) i used following code

```
NSURL(string: "myurl.php?deviceName=name ’phone".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())!)
```

It will not decode properly.
please tell me how i can encode special charater in swift2.0 ?

**EDIT :**
Eric D answer is right but when i encode below `stringURL`  it will not encode properly.
Why?

```
let stringURL = "https://my.server.com/login.php?e=email&dn=my’s iPad&d=5&er=D550772E-34BB-4DCB-89C9-E746FAD83D24&tz=330"
        print(stringURL)
        let charSet = NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet()
        let encoded = stringURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(charSet)!

        let url = NSURL(string: encoded.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())!)!

        print(url) //https%253A//my.server.com/login.php%253Fe=email&dn=my%25E2%2580%2599s%2520iPad&d=5&er=D550772E-34BB-4DCB-89C9-E746FAD83D ... 4&tz=330
```

**EDIT 2:**

How to encode **NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding** in **swift2.0** ?

Comment: try `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()` because the special characters occur the in `query` part of the URL

Comment: @ vadian it will not work. in server i got response like myNameâ€™s iPhone

Comment: URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet() not work

Comment: The method `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` expects `UTF-8` encoded strings. You might need to convert the string from  `WindowsCP1250` to `UTF-8` first

Comment: @vadian not able to solve the problem, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet()` as character set:

```
let stringURL = "myurl.php?deviceName=name'phone"
let charSet = NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet()
let encoded = stringURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(charSet)!
let url = NSURL(string: encoded)!

print(url)  // "myurl.php%3FdeviceName=name'phone"
```

*Note that `'` doesn't have to be encoded, it's a valid URL character.*

*Update:* in the comments you state that it's still not working because your encoded URL is truncated and contains `...`, but actually this is likely to be just a *printed description* truncated by NSURL; the actual URL contained by the NSURL object should be ok. Otherwise it would be nil. You should check on your server side for problems with very long but correct URLs.

Comment: What makes you say it's still not encoded properly? You may want to add more details and context about what you expect to happen and why it's different from what is happening. Thank you.

Comment: in my edit question when i encode large string it will encode  .... after some character. just like this //https%253A//my.server.com/login.php%253Fe=email&dn=my%25E2%2580%2599s%2520iPad&d=5&er=D550772E-34BB-4DCB-89C9-E746FAD83D ... 4&tz=330

Comment: that why when i pass above url to my server it will return my custom error

Comment: Are you sure there's still an error? The dots in the truncated url description are likely to be just that, a truncated *description* when printed. The actual url held by NSURL is usually ok if it's not nil. You should check on the server side for errors with long (correct) URLs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90861/discussion-between-rizwan-shaikh-and-eric-d).

Comment: Looks like URLPathAllowedCharacterSet should be used only for non-web urls. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
let newURLEncodedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Comment: i check it will not work for special character . on server side it will decode like myNameâ€™s iPhone