# NSURL from String gets truncated, dots on the UIVideoEditorController's video path Swift 2 iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, nsurl

I can't get the full NSURL of the editedVideoPath, here's my code:

```
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
    var videoPath = String()
    var videoURL = NSURL()


// Video Editor delegate
func videoEditorController(editor: UIVideoEditorController, didSaveEditedVideoToPath editedVideoPath: String) {
        if saveToPhotoLibrary {
            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(editedVideoPath) {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(editedVideoPath, self, nil, nil)
            }
            print("SAVED TO PHOTO LIBRARY AT: \(editedVideoPath)")
         }

        videoPath = editedVideoPath
        videoURL = NSURL(string: editedVideoPath)!
        print("VIDEO PATH: \(videoPath)")
        print("VIDEO URL: \(videoURL)")
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The problem is the I can't get the full NSURL out of the **videoPath** string, here's what the XCode console prints out:

```
VIDEO PATH: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D7536AD4-353A-48CA-8F31-2D78F9F10730/tmp/trim.BFF7D20F-138A-46A2-A58E-76736AF7343E.MOV
VIDEO URL: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D7536AD4-353A-48CA-8F31-2D78F9F10730/tmp/trim.BFF7D20F-138A-46A2-A58E-76 ... 343E.MOV
```

As you can see, the VIDEO URL gets dots almost by the end of it, while the VideoPath string is correct. This is a pretty wired issue I've never encountered before with this NSURL statement:

```
    videoURL = NSURL(string: editedVideoPath)!
```

Since I need to upload that edited video to a web server, I need its full correct url. I thought is was a **print()** issue, but if I try to grab the **videoURL** XCode tells me that it's nil, so **print()** function tells the truth :(

I've searched here and there on stackoverflow, no success.

Hope someone can help,
Thanks!

Comment: The dots are only in the *representation* of the URL when printed if it's very long. The URL itself is ok. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32820623/2227743

Comment: That would be a great news, then I don't know why, if i try to convert the videoURL to NSData it gives me = nil  let videoData = NSData(contentsOfUrl: videoURL)!

Comment: Mm... Did you try `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: editedVideoPath)`? I just realized you're using a file path, not a network path.

Comment: Yep, it works. Hope it wasn't you who down voted my question, anyway that was the key, thanks!

Comment: Are you kidding? I'm helping you, why would I downvote... :p I'm writing a proper answer now.

Comment: Right, I actually just realized who did it :) thanks again, you saved my day ;)

Comment: No problem. ;) And you're welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using a file path, you want to use

```
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: editedVideoPath)
```

instead of

```
NSURL(string: editedVideoPath)
```